# Android Wait for user input at AlertDialog to proceed

Tags: android, wait, android-alertdialog

I've see this subject been discussed here but can't seem to understand how to proceed.

In my `onCreate` I have code that checks if it is the first run of the application `firstRun = getPref.getBoolean("firstRun", true);`. If its the first time that the app is run, an alertdialog is shown with a message saying thats there is no database installed and the user as to press the `OK` button to download the database. If there are no errors than `pref.putBoolean("firstRun", false);` and the alertdialog it's not shown in the next runs.

Now I want to introduce a `ChangeLog` that it is only shown on the first run after the app is installed or upgraded. Since the changelog must come before the `firstRun` check, I should wait for the user press the changelog alertdialog `OK` button.

I've created the code for the changelog (it's working as expected) and after that code, I have the code of the `firstRun`. The problem is that the changelog is shown but than, if its in fact the first run of the app, the `firstRun` alertdialog is overlapping the changelog alertdialog.

So, here is my question.

What's the best wait to proceed so that the `firstRun` code is only executed after the user presses the `OK` button on the changelog alertdialog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I understand is that the `changeLog` will run every first run of the app. So you can override `onDismiss()` of your `changeLog AlertDialog`. Then just put your code for `firstRun` check

```
@Override
public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog)
{
    // firstRun Check
    // call function to run AlertDialog code for first check if firstRun == true else close dialog
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take another boolean variable `isChengelog`  and set it false initialy, when user click on `ChangeLog` dialog set it true and save it in preferences. Further proceeding code check

```
if(isChengelog){
  //Show firstRun Aleret dialog
} 
else{
 //Not Show firstRun Aleret dialog
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Mukesh suggested but also put this in your callback for your changelog dialog.

```
// On "OK clicked"
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
    pref.putBoolean("changelog", false);
    showFirstRunDialog();
}
```

Define a convenience function to show the first run dialog:

```
public void showFirstRunDialog(){
    if(getPref.getBoolean("firstRun", true);) {
        //show dialog
    }
}
```

Make sure you include Mukesh's suggestion on start-up:

```
if(getPref.getBoolean("changelog", true);){
  //Show changelog dialog
} 
else{
   showFirstRunDialog();
}
```