# onDismiss() for a DialogFragment

Tags: android, arraylist, dialog

I have an activity named ActividadPrincipal where I have a ListView filled with an Action ArrayList (Action is the type) named listaActions. When I click in a button, it shows a DialogFragment where I can create an Action object and add it to the list.

I would like to actualize my ListView with that list just when I come back from that Dialog... Is it possible? I tried several ways but I still can't do it.

I also tried what users say here: [Android Wait for user input at AlertDialog to proceed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18830899/android-wait-for-user-input-at-alertdialog-to-proceed), but I can't use onDismiss() because I have a DialogFragment and not a DialogInterface. I tried to create an onDismiss() but it doesn't work. Also tried to do this: [DialogFragment and onDismiss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23786033/dialogfragment-and-ondismiss) but doesn't work.

Any idea?

Comment: Seems like this is what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/a/13433770/3194316